# Questions on method return values and arguments after do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

sorry for this noob question I am just not able to understand ruby/rails grammer,

In rails 2.x, I read the following code,

```
def localized_input_form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc)
    options = args.extract_options!
    args << options.merge(:builder=>LocalizedFormBuilder)
    concat('<div class="inputbox">')
    form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc)
    concat('</div>')
end
```

What does the above function return? Shouldn't it be the return value of the last line statement `concat('</div>')`?

In the views, I have,

```
<% localized_input_form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
```

What is the f in the above code, is it the same f as `form_for(xx) do |f|`?

The following code works without problem,

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :required => true, :size => 30,:class =>'ime_on' %>
```

In rails 4, I made the following modification,

```
def localized_input_form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc)
    options = args.extract_options!
    args << options.merge(:builder=>LocalizedFormBuilder)
    concat('<div class="inputbox">'.html_safe)
    concat(form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc))
    concat('</div>'.html_safe)
end
```

Without adding concat out of form_for, and without adding html_safe, the original code just doesnt work.

Now, everything still works, the

```
<% localized_input_form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
```

works without problem, the form is shown exactly as before. So what is the return value of this function now? and what is f above?

The only difference is, the original options in

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :required => true, :size => 30,:class =>'ime_on' %>
```

which are, required: true, size: 30, and class:'ime_on' don't show in the final html!

It generates the following,

```
<input type="text" value="abc" name="customer[name]" id="customer_name">
```

without size, class etc options. The html generated by rails 2.x do have these options showing up.

I am just confused about the difference. And I also don't understand why the original rails 2.x and rails 4 both worked (the |f| reflects the form generated by form_for, so f.text_field will get the right value from database).

Comment: What class is it in?

Comment: the method is in helper class, it's inside "module ApplicationHelper
". There is also a localized_form_builder helper, but I think it only modifies the way that how label is generated, it doesn't include any code on text_field.

Comment: As far as I know `concat` forces output to the final rendered view, it's not returned. It's sort of like `puts` to browser.

Comment: thanks, but what is the do |f| then? shouldn't the f be the return value of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your method will return the last line. In your case this is `concat("</div>")` which evaluates to just `"</div>"`.

The problem is, that `concat` is not acting as you expect, because it's not occurring within a text buffer and so there's nothing to "concat" to.

To fix this, wrap your helper in a `capture` block like so:

```
def some_html
  capture do
    # ...
    concat('<div class="inputbox">')
    # ...
    concat('</div>>
  end
end
```

More on the `capture` method: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/capture